# Conditional expectation of a product XY given Z with Y independent of Z

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $X,Y$
  and $Z$
  be integrable random variables s.t. $XY$
  is integrable and $Y$
  is independent of $Z$
 .

I was wondering if there are any helpful/common ways of rewriting $\mathbb{E}[XY\mid Z]$ when $Y$ is independent of $Z$
  (and nothing more is known)?

For example, if $X$
  and $Y$
  are conditionally independent given $Z$
 , then (more or less by definition - depending on your point of view)

$\mathbb{E}[XY\mid Z]=\mathbb{E}[X\mid Z]\mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z]$.

But this is quite clearly not true in general.

Comment: Indeed. Knowing *only* that $Y\perp Z$ is of no help.  About all you can say is: $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(XY\mid Z) =&~ \mathsf E(Y\,\mathsf E(X\mid Y,Z)\mid Z)\\[1ex]=&~ \mathsf E(X\,\mathsf E(Y\mid X,Z)\mid Z)\end{align}$$Nothing will simplify *unless* you also have conditional independence; which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: @ProbStudent Did the answer and comments answer your question? (If not, let us know how to why, and how to address the remaining doubts).

Comment: @ClementC. I have accepted your answer. However, I was already aware of the points you are making. I was more looking to see if perhaps there were some examples of mild extra assumptions that allowed to get good (algrebraic) expressions for the conditional expectation of a product when one of the variable is independent of what you're conditioning on. But the unfortunate answer is probably that there really are not any such useful assumptions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Not in general.**

First, note that if $XY,Z$ are independent:
$$
\mathbb{E}[XY\mid Z] = \mathbb{E}[XY]
$$
which is "just a number."

Now, it's tempting to try and say something in the case that if $XY,Z$ are *not* independent. *But...*

- If $X=f(Z)$ for some function $f$, then:
  $$
  \mathbb{E}[XY\mid Z] = \mathbb{E}[f(Z)Y\mid Z] = f(Z)\mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z]
  = X\mathbb{E}[Y]
  $$
  which is not equal to $\mathbb{E}[XY]$ in general. For instance, if $X=Z$ is a Rademacher r.v. (uniform on $\{-1,1\}$) independent of $Y\sim\operatorname{Bern}(1/2)$, then $X\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{1}{2}X$ but $\mathbb{E}[XY]=0$.
- If $X,Y$ are independent Rademacher random variables and $Z=XY$, then (easy to check) we do have $X,Y,Z$ pairwise independent, and clearly $XY,Z$ not independent:
  $$
  \mathbb{E}[XY\mid Z] = \mathbb{E}[Z\mid Z] = Z = XY\neq X\mathbb{E}[Y] = 0.
  $$
  (and $Z\neq \mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[Z] = 0$ either.)

so you will need more assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

In Durret example 4.1.7. there is a nice formula that might be helpful in such a setting
[image]

For example it could be that you can write $X=X_{1}X_{2}$ where $X_{1}$ is independent of $Y$ and $X_{2}$ correlates with it and so then you would apply this for $\tilde{X}=X_{1}$ and $\tilde{Y}=X_{2}Y$ and $Z=X_{1}$.